# Stability with input same as with nonlinear function?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, control-theory, stability-in-odes, stability-theory

Assume there is a dynamical system

$$
\frac{d x(t)}{dt} = A \cdot x(t) + q(x(t))
$$

and that $A$ is stable and that $q$ is a nonlinear and very complicated function. We only know $q$ is smooth and bounded from above and below and that $0$ is the only fixpoint.

Can't I just replace $q$ with a "fake disturbance input" $d$:

$$
\frac{d x(t)}{dt} = A \cdot x(t) + d(t)
$$

and show that this system is input to state stable for a bounded $d(t)$? (which is much easier)

Doesn't that also show that the system with $q$ is stable or am I missing something?

Comment: Without knowing more about $q$, it could partially or fully counteract the characteristic properties of $A$. At least as long as $x$ is moderately large. In the situation $\|x\|\gg M\ge \|q(y)\|$ one can in first order remove $q$ as a (relatively) small perturbation, so that indeed the system behavior is governed by the stability of $A$.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Yes so was my thought, then $x \rightarrow \infty$ is impossible

Comment: The easiest way would be to use some Lyapunov argument where $V(x)=\|x\|^2$ and $\dot V\le -a\|x\|^2+b\|x\|$ would then give $\|x\|\le\frac ba$ as trapping sphere.